# Creating a array of views and items + editing them

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to make a status bar app on OSX with Swift. I want to programmatically create a view for each people connected to my website.

In these views I want a :

- Image
- Label
- Progress Bar

I want these items to be editable anytime.

This is my actual code :

```
var items: [AnyObject] = []
var views: [AnyObject] = []
var images: [AnyObject] = []
var texts: [AnyObject] = []
var bars: [AnyObject] = []

for var i = 0; i < 5; i++ {
        var item : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "item\(i)", action: Selector("nil"), keyEquivalent: "")
        statusItem.menu!.addItem(NSMenuItem.separatorItem())
        statusItem.menu!.addItem(item)
        statusItem.menu!.addItem(NSMenuItem.separatorItem())
        items.append(item)

        let view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 265, height: 71))
        item = Menu.itemWithTitle("item\(i)")!
        item.view = view
        views.append(view)

        var image: NSImageView
        image = NSImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 9, width: 50, height: 50))
        image.image = NSImage(named: "MacbookAir")
        view.addSubview(image)
        images.append(image)

        var text: NSTextField
        text = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 96, y: 42, width: 158, height: 17))
        text.stringValue = "MacBook Air"
        text.editable = false
        text.bordered = false
        text.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 1, alpha: 0)
        view.addSubview(text)
        texts.append(text)

        var bar: NSProgressIndicator
        bar = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 82, y: 7, width: 163, height: 20))
        bar.indeterminate = false
        bar.incrementBy(20.0)
        view.addSubview(bar)
        bars.append(bar)
    }

}
```

I know I'm doing it the wrong way because in my head I wanted to do something like :

```
var bar[i]: NSProgressIndicator
        bar[i] = NSProgressIndicator(frame: CGRect(x: 82, y: 7, width: 163, height: 20))
        bar[i].indeterminate = false
        bar[i].incrementBy(20.0)
        view[i].addSubview(bar[i])
        bars.append(bar[i])
```

Then it would be editable like that :

```
bar[0].incrementBy(50.0) //incrementing the bar with the array index
```

That is definitely not working at all...
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT (adding more infos) :**

When I print all my arrays I'm getting all of this code :

```
   /////Printing Items :
[<NSMenuItem: 0x6000000a1f20 item0>, <NSMenuItem: 0x6000000a2100 item1>, <NSMenuItem: 0x6000000a2340 item2>, <NSMenuItem: 0x6000000a2580 item3>, <NSMenuItem: 0x6000000a27c0 item4>]
/////Printing Views :
[<NSView: 0x600000120820>, <NSView: 0x6000001208c0>, <NSView: 0x600000120960>, <NSView: 0x600000120a00>, <NSView: 0x600000120aa0>]
/////Printing Texts :
[<NSTextField: 0x6080001e0d00>, <NSTextField: 0x6000001e0400>, <NSTextField: 0x6000001e0700>, <NSTextField: 0x6000001e0900>, <NSTextField: 0x6000001e0b00>]
/////Printing images :
[<NSImageView: 0x600000161f80>, <NSImageView: 0x600000161ec0>, <NSImageView: 0x600000162040>, <NSImageView: 0x600000162100>, <NSImageView: 0x6000001621c0>]
/////Printing Bars :
[<NSProgressIndicator: 0x6080001e0e00>, <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e0600>, <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e0800>, <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e0a00>, <NSProgressIndicator: 0x6000001e0c00>]
```

Is there a way to modify bars, texts etc... ?

Comment: What is specifically wrong with your code?

Comment: @rocky hey, I updated my post if you can help finding something... Thanks !

Comment: What does "That is definitely not working at all" even _mean_?

Comment: And what is the iOS part of this question? If there is none, take out that tag please.

Comment: It means that the thing that the code below the "I know I'm doing it the wrong way because in my head I wanted to do something like :" is not working (showing me a lot of errors)

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking into consideration threading?

As NSStatusbar is part of the UI it's probably being fired on the main-thread. So if anything, i'd perform any updates to it via something like:

```
//Swift
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    //do what you have to do here
}
```